# How fallible are DNA paternity tests?

Tags: dna

Is it possible to get either a false positive or a false negative from a DNA paternity test and what would be the likely mechanisms behind this?  For example, is it possible that a father's DNA could have changed during his lifetime enough to be unrecognisable to that of his children?

Comment: Only when the lab made a mistake and exchanged samples. Otherwise not.

Comment: Try to make the test again, in different place..

Comment: Thanks I we did take one mouth swap from one company then we did a blood test with another just to be sure. Both test came back negative.  Just confused with the similarities.

Comment: @lou It would be nice if you refrain from bringing your personal issues in the post. Just ask a neutral question.

Comment: I know. Just didn't know how to explain the situation for someone with knowledge about dna ect to help me with my question.

Comment: @lou hopefully that edit helps a bit

Answer (score 4):

Discounting lab error and other kinds of human incompetence, there aren't very many things that can confound a paternity test. Normal DNA damage cannot, but there are kinds of genetic chimeras that get strange results.

Normal human DNA damage can't add up fast enough to change the results without killing you several times over, but there are a surprisingly large number of people who are chimeras.

The relevant particular flavor of chimerism is [tetragametic chimerism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_%28genetics%29#Tetragametic_chimerism), where essentially parts of your body are sibling-related to the rest. This occasionally is discovered during paternity testing, in one vivid instance when [a woman was provably not the mother of the newborn that she had just given birth to.](http://www.businessinsider.com/lydia-fairchild-is-her-own-twin-2014-2) Technically I suppose the baby was her skin's niece.

The incidence of this was thought to be very low, but it's almost impossible to detect without DNA testing. We know the incidence is much higher than we thought, but we don't know how high.